# generator expression with value check

Tags: python, python-2.7, generator, list-comprehension

I have the following snippet of code to find out whether any pair from a given list of numbers matches a given sum.

I have implemented the function as follows

```
def google(numbers, total):
    complement =[]
    for x in numbers:
        if x in complement:
            return True
        else: complement.append(total-x)
    return False

print google([1,2,3,4,5],8)
```

My question is, is there ANY POSSIBLE way of implementing this as a generator expression. ?

For example is there a way to check if the currently partially created generator has a given value inside comprehension ?

Comment: A generator and a list comprehension are two different things. Which do you mean?

Comment: It can't be an equivalent if only for the fact comprehensions do not have a way to short-circuit like loops. You could filter, but that would be clunky to do. What about just `def google(numbers, total): return total in map(sum, combinations(numbers, r=2))`

Comment: Agreed @ReutSharabani. For those who are not familiar with it, to use `combinations()` as @ReutSharabani suggests you'll need to include the line `from itertools import combinations` first.

Comment: Note: they're generator *expressions*, not comprehensions.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to do this, all things are possible, but not all things are desirable:

```
from itertools import combinations, dropwhile

def google(numbers, total):
    return bool(next(dropwhile(lambda c: sum(c) != total, combinations(numbers, 2)), False))
```

We iterate through all the possible 2-number combinations of `numbers` using `combinations` and compare them to `total`.

Using `dropwhile`, we can emulate the short-circuit behaviour of your original code, getting only the *first* combination that satisfies the condition, if it exists. It will then, as a non-empty `tuple`, be converted to the boolean literal `True`. Otherwise, `next` will see that `dropwhile` is empty, and return the default value `False`.

Testing:

```
print(google([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 8))
print(google([1, 2, 3, 4], 8))
```

Output:

```
True
False
```

Comment: @DavisHerring I was trying multiple solutions and got distracted. There is actually no need for `chain`.